# Consistent derivation of private key from PassKey?

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, passkey

Can I consistently derive a private key that *isn’t* the PassKey *from* a PassKey?

Eg. so that I could use that derived key in-application across multiple different devices without having to use a both-online-at-the-same-time exchange method (eg. Diffie-Hellman) to securely share a generated key between devices?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [PRF extension](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#prf-extension) to Webauthn, which can be used to derive a secret from a FIDO2 credential such as a passkey.  Now, some browsers and password managers may support it and some may not, but it is available.